# Mongodb - Can I find a nested object using $gt statement?

Tags: mongodb

this is my mongodb object:

```
{
  ...
  "position" : {
    "x" : 1,
    "y" : 1
  }
}
```

I want to find objects which have position.x greater than 0. So I try this statement in Java.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("position",
                        new BasicDBObject("x", 
                          new BasicDBObject("$gt", 0));
// { "position" : { "x" : { "$gt" : 0}}}
DBCursor cursor = db.map.find(query);
```

But cursor is null. How can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When querying on values that are nested in documents, you need to use the `.` operator in the query part of your `find()` call.

I'm not up on the Java driver for MongoDB, but you can give this a shot:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("position.x",
                          new BasicDBObject("$gt", 0));
DBCursor cursor = db.map.find(query);
```

Ultimately, the query you're looking for is `{ "position.x" : { "$gt" : 0}}`

Comment: It works greate on Mongodb JAVA! There is a simple solution. Thank you so much!